# Move Dialog Message/Title to right side

Tags: java, android, dialog, string-formatting, string.format

Inside my app I have simple dialog but I have problem to move message/title to right corner side. I found a solution to move to right but distance is hardcoded (I need to tell how much char to right) it looks like :

```
builder.setTitle(String.format("%20s","1/10"));
```

where "%20s" tells that it moves to right for 20chars. There is an option to do it in other way where I don't need to tell how much to right just it take place in right corner/end of line ? I want to have this message in right corner in all screen sizes devices.

Answer (score 1):

Try this out:

```
AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
builder.setTitle("My Title");
builder.setMessage("your message");
builder.setPositiveButton("OK", null);

AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();
TextView messageText = (TextView)dialog.findViewById(android.R.id.message);
messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);
dialog.show();
```

If you want right alignment, just change `messageText.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER);` to `messageText.setGravity(Gravity.RIGHT);`.

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Probably it's good but It's not exaxtly what I want. First of all I have quite advanced Dialog and I can't use this line "AlertDialog dialog = builder.show();" because I'm already using it and can't use it again in other place. Second It works for all message string and I want to move just part of it. I'm most interesting in some kind of String.format expression like this "%20s" but you know it should move for all cases to right side